# Windows 10 Clipboard

Tags: microsoft-windows, os-clipboard

[Windows 10 has a clipboard history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/clipboard-in-windows-10-c436501e-985d-1c8d-97ea-fe46ddf338c6) which can be accessed using WIN+V it has a recent history of all your copy and paste. When using this in VIM and trying to paste from it doesn't work it acts like nothing happens. Wondering if there's a way to make it usable in VIM. The alternative is opening up a notepad and just windows copying from there which is just extra steps.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: On my laptop, WIN+V works as expected, pasting into Vim 8.0 (in Insert Mode) in Windows Terminal - Ubuntu and Windows Terminal - OpenSUSE. (In Normal Mode, it ignores what I paste until it hits one of `A, a, I, i, O, o, R, S, s`; then pastes the remainder.) When I try to do it in WSL - Ubuntu and WSL - OpenSUSE (in Insert Mode or in Normal Mode), Vim enters Visual Block Mode.  In GVim 8.2, in Insert Mode `⊞v` prints a caret `^`, and in Normal Mode it enters Visual Block Mode, allowing me to select a rectangular block of text. Curious.

Comment: Win-V (aka `⊞v`) should have no effect except to open the clipboard history window. Windows intercepts Win-V before it reaches a window. It's when you click on a row in the history window that some keystroke is sent to the window from which you entered Win-V. And that keystroke is as I describe in my answer: Ctrl-V or similar. _That one_ can have the kind of effects you describe. Are you sure you have this feature enabled?

Comment: I did not have ⊞v enabled at first -- I seem to remember disabling "clipboard history" a few years ago, because, if my memory is correct, `ctrl-v` (back then) invoked the clipboard history, and I hated getting lots of irrelevant options (instead of what was most recently in the clipboard).  But, I had to turn it on to try it and get the results I described above.  Win10 helpfully pops up a message about enabling it, if you press ⊞v with clipboard history disabled.  Now that it's on, I'll probably keep it enabled.

Comment: @GideonSassoon Did my answer address your question?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like selecting something from that window leads to Windows doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in an attempt to paste. That, of course, doesn't mean the same thing in Vim. However, if you have things properly set up to catch clipboard text in register `*` (see `:h 'clipboard'`) then all you'd need to do after clicking an item in the window is hit `p` in Vim. (If that doesn't work see if `"*p` does.)

I just tried it and `p` does work for me.

(There are ways to make Ctrl-V do a put in Vim but that's a bit more obtrusive.)

**Update:** I was playing around a bit with this and it appears to be a little smarter than just Ctrl-V pasting everywhere. For instance, in my mintty terminal that I use for Cygwin it successfully pastes but it can't be using Ctrl-V as that does nothing. I do have both <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> set up to act like Ctrl-V, though, and it seems that it detected one of these.